# Android Studio - How can I retrieve data from my database with a WHERE clause?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch 1 row of data from my database using a cursor. I then try to print specific columns from the cursor. I am getting an error "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1"

Java code:

```
public class edit_student_form extends AppCompatActivity {
    private dbasemanager dBase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_student_form);

        Button saveNewRecordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveNewRecord);
        saveNewRecordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dBase = new dbasemanager(this);
                Cursor row = dBase.retrieveOneRow("18367557");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), row.getString(0) + ", " + row.getString(1) + ", " + row.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

retrieveOneRow() Function:

```
    public Cursor retrieveOneRow(String sId) {
    String[] columns = new String[] {"sid", "first_name", "last_name", "gender",
            "course_study", "age", "address"};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, columns, "sid=?", new String[] { sId }, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.getTYPE(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME))

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX Could you elaborate? Where would I place that?

Comment: Where you get your cursor

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX below the query?

Comment: Cursor row = dBase.retrieveOneRow("18367557");

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX It worked. Thanks